# Call Multi-WebApi at same time cause A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**Happen when calling multi-API(query from dbContext) at the same time**

```
 A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.
```

**.Net Core 2.2 (web API only)**

**Mssql 2014**

**Vue (Front-end)**

-Trying to add MultipleActiveResultSets=True in connect string

-Trying to make dbContext in Transient Mode

still failed

startUp.cs

```cs
services.AddDbContext<BaseContext>(options => options
.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
.UseSqlServer(connStr), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Api Initialize

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BaseContext _context;

        public ValuesController(BaseContext test) { _context = test; }
```

```cs
// POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post(SearchCodeFileRequest search, int page = 1)
        {
            var result = GetList(search, page);

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

function used by api

```cs
private List<TestModel> GetList(SearchCodeFileRequest search, int page = 1)
        {
                var data = _context.Category.Include(a => a.CategoryParentCategoryItem).Where(a => !a.IsDeleted);

                var list = data.Select(a => new TestModel
                               {
                                   id = a.GID,
                                   parentName =
                                       a.ItemCategory == null ? "" : a.ItemCategory.ItemDescription,
                                   desc = a.ItemDescription,
                                   itemCode = a.ItemCode,
                                   locked = a.Lock,
                                   childrenCnt = a.CategoryParentCategoryItem == null
                                       ? 0
                                       : a.CategoryParentCategoryItem.Count(c => !c.IsDeleted)
                               })
                               .ToList();
                return list;
        }
```

Front-End Call Api with jwt

```
test() {
      const api = '/api/values';
      this.$http
        .post(api, this.search)
    },

created() {
    this.test();
    this.test();
    this.test();
    this.test();
  },
```

Sometimes happened with

`An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.`

Don't know the root cause, it already creates a new db instance each time Api called ??

really thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the lifetime of the `controllers` - did you customized the registration of them?

Comment: Not very sure what you mean, is there any symbol if customized?

Comment: You could register the API controllers with a different `ServiceLifetime`. When a controller is `ServiceLifetime.Singleton` every injected object is automatically also a singleton to this instance.

Comment: Do you call multiple times `GetList` in the same request? If you call `data.ToList() ` directly, will you get the same error? Can you reproduce your issue with a simple demo?

Comment: It will become  An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Data.BaseContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually ca
used by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This co
uld also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.
   at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for all you guys, I already found the problem is from middleware which also accesses dbContext,and share the same dbcontext
really thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

create and dispose the context within the method instead of using a global context.

```
using (var _context = new context()) 
{
  _context.Category.Include(a => a.CategoryParentCategoryItem).Where(a => !a.IsDeleted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change code as Terrencep said.
but still pop out the same error

```cs
private List<CodeFileListModel> GetList(SearchCodeFileRequest search, int page = 1)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json")
                                               .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BaseContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetSection("DbSetting").GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            using (var contextText = new BaseContext(builder.Options))
            {
                var data = contextText.Category.Include(a => a.CategoryParentCategoryItem).Where(a => !a.IsDeleted);

                var list = data.Select(a => new CodeFileListModel
                               {
                                   id = a.GID,
                                   parentName =
                                       a.ItemCategory == null ? "" : a.ItemCategory.ItemDescription,
                                   desc = a.ItemDescription,
                                   itemCode = a.ItemCode,
                                   locked = a.Lock,
                                   childrenCnt = a.CategoryParentCategoryItem == null
                                       ? 0
                                       : a.CategoryParentCategoryItem.Count(c => !c.IsDeleted)
                               })
                               .ToList();

                return list;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How did you fix this issue?